# Converting VARCHAR column to FLOAT in SQL Server cuts off digits

Tags: sql, sql-server, floating-point, type-conversion

I'm working with a `ProjectID` column in a SQL Server database that starts out as `VARCHAR(255)` from its source (either Quickbase or an Excel file) and needs to end up as a `FLOAT` (for various reasons, mainly because it's a primary key across many DB tables and needs to match existing formatting).

The trouble is, when I convert the column to `FLOAT` using `TRY_CONVERT`, it cuts off digits and I can't figure out why. The table below shows a sample of the actual values in their original `VARCHAR(255)` state and their converted `FLOAT` state.

**What baffles me is**: if I use `TRY_CONVERT` on any one of the values on the left individually, it doesn't cut off digits. When I `TRY_CONVERT` the whole column, it **DOES** cut off digits -- but only for some values.

- `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, '10189.13808')` results in 10189.13808 (expected result)
- `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, '15336.19001')` results in 15336.19001 (expected result)
- `SELECT TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, '13615.1115')` results in 13615.1115 (expected result)

| ProjectID - Original VARCHAR(255) | ProjectID - TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT) on entire column |
| --- | --- |
| 10189.13808 | 10189.1 |
| 15669.752 | 15669.752 |
| 4940.19 | 4940.19 |
| 15336.19001 | 15336.2 |
| 55.1115 | 55.1115 |
| 13615.1115 | 13615.1 |

I've tried converting the column first to `DECIMAL(18,6)`, then to `FLOAT`, but it produces the same result. I've also tried `TRY_CAST`. Unfortunately I can't keep the column as `VARCHAR` because a few existing processes in the DB use the `FLOOR` of the `ProjectID` to get the non-decimal portion and it would be involved to go and change that now.

How can I get these values into `FLOAT` without losing scale?

Comment: You do understand how floating point numbers work right? They can't accurately store all values. They are only intended for scientific usage. Everything you have shown would be much better off represented by a decimal. Although that's a weird PK - int is better

Comment: Float PK, that's a first (and i don't mean it in a good way). I think you are not mentioning something here, because your cast shouldn't remove decimals. I'm guessing you're doing something else which does though, alternatively the datatypes aren't exactly what you say they are. You need to provide whole sql as well as table definitions

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert these stringy things to `float`? Why can't you just create a primary key constraint over the top of the `varchar(255)` column? Although they have digits it's probably a mistake to consider these to be numbers - what happens when you get a sub-sub-project with two dots in it, `123.456.789`?

Comment: @siggemannen This is not a primary key, it's a project ID composed of a store # (before the decimal) and project code (after the decimal). It will only ever have this format of ###.####. The primary key is completely separate and not part of my post and is an integer column.

Comment: @DaleK These values are successfully stored as FLOAT many times elsewhere in the database. I understand it can be better represented by decimal in theory but this is a project ID and a decimal would add trailing zeros which is not desirable nor functional in this scenario. What I'm trying to get answered here is why TRY_CONVERT doesn't affect the integrity of the data on a single-conversion basis, but why it does when the whole column is converted at once.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I explained in my post why this has to be a FLOAT in this situation. I would like for it not to be a FLOAT, but for now that's how I need to format it for the database. There will never be a sub-sub project as this is not a WBS code.

Comment: Please include the whole script, otherwise it's not possible to reproduce your scenario.